# Enviar mail automaticamente con SpreadSheets

Tags: javascript, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Estoy trabajando con un formulario de google en cual guarda los resultados es una hoja de calculo en google drive.

Desde la columna B2 se guardan los correos electronicos de los usuario que completan el formulario y en google script tengo este codigo que envia los mails pero de forma manual, como puedo hacer para que se ejecute de manera automatica?

Gracias!

```
function enviarCorreos() {
const libro = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
libro.setActiveSheet(libro.getSheetByName("Candidatos"));
const hoja = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
const filas = hoja.getRange("A2:E3").getValues();

  for (indiceFila in filas) {
    var candidato = crearCandidato(filas[indiceFila]);
    enviarCorreo(candidato);
  }
}
function crearCandidato(datosFila) {
  const candidato = {
  momento: datosFila[0],
  email: datosFila[1],
  nombre: datosFila[2],
  bla: datosFila[3],
  blabla: datosFila[4]
};
return candidato;
}
function enviarCorreo(candidato) {
  MailApp.sendEmail(candidato.email,"Resultado","del test.");
}
```

Comment: Una de estas respuestas te puede servir https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232405/detect-user-inserting-row-or-column-in-a-google-spreadsheet-and-reacting-in-a-sc

Comment: Muchas gracias!